# PhoneGap Javascript code is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am developing an app using the PhoneGap/Cordova development framework. I am attempting to get the first portion of my app done, which simply outputs the time it takes for the mobile device to compute a million math functions (I'm analyzing the performance of the application). The issue is though that nothing seems to be printing out and all I have is a white screen. Here is my code:
https://github.com/messichess77/Phonegap-Processing

The specific js file that I call in the index.html is located here:
https://github.com/messichess77/Phonegap-Processing/blob/master/assets/www/processing.js

Thank you very much to anyone who can help! Sorry for being such a noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but it could be something along the lines of `app.initalize();` not being completed before it starts your processing.js.

Instead, why don't you try something along the lines of first wrapping your processing.js into a function, for example let's say `doTheMath(){...}`.  Then, move the processing.js file into the `js/` folder just to keep the structure of files within PhoneGap.

Then, in your index.html, do something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", doTheMath, false);
</script>
```

Also, for starters, just try a small number of calculations to make sure the app actually works, then you can adjust it to a ridiculous amount like a million.  I say this because it's possible that it could just be taking forever to do those million calculations and just shows a white screen during that.

Comment: Yeah, I first tried out decreasing the number of calculations (first to 100, then 1) and I still got the white screen. Then I added the function and moved the processing.js file to the js/ folder. It still didn't work though. Any other possible reason why its not working?

Comment: I would try double checking the syntax of the javascript.  Right now i'm not in a location to try and look but in a couple hours hopefully I can.